# What user input should I use for triggering a function when text inside the input field changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

What user input should I use for triggering a function when text inside the input field changes?
I have an input field in which I have put a time picker.
I want to trigger a function whenever the user selects the input field and picks a time.
There is no explicit way to trigger a function when a new time is picked from the timer so I am triggering a function on (blur) and I tried to do it with (change) but that not working

Comment: What timepicker are you using?

Comment: `(ngModelChange)="inputChanged($event)"`

Comment: You can use formcontrols and registers to the changes. Everytime somthing in your form changes (doesnt matter what) it triggers.

Comment: What about you use reactive forms and subscribe to `valueChanges` formControl ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using Angular Material Timepicker from ngx-timepicker https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no explicit way to trigger a function when a new time is picked...

That seems odd to me, but I don't do much Angular, so maybe it's normal to rely on DOM events instead.

If it's an [`input` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), one hopes that whatever timepicker you're using would fire the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) and/or [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) events on it, so you could use those. Prefer `input` to `change` as it fires even when the user hasn't left the field yet (whereas `change` doesn't, necessarily, but again it will depend on the timepicker).